# Is there a way to assign number of incremental value in a new column of each rows based current and previous row values of existing columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, df and I want to add incremental ID number in a new column based on current and previous row of another column.

```
data = [{'X': 6, 'Y': 1}, {'X': 6, 'Y': 1}, {'X': 7, 'Y': 0}, {'X': 7, 'Y': 0},
        {'X': 6, 'Y': 1}, {'X': 7, 'Y': 1}, {'X': 7, 'Y': 0}, {'X': 7, 'Y': 1} ] 

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Now this is the condition,

if Current X = Previous X & Current Y <> Previous Y,

Then ID_Number = New Incremented Number

OR

if Current X <> Previous X & Current Y = Previous Y,

Then ID_Number = New Incremented Number

OR

if Current X = Previous X & Current Y = Previous Y,

Then ID_Number = Same as Previous ID_Number

OR

if Current X <> Previous X & Current Y <> Previous Y,

Then ID_Number = New Incremented Number

Input Dataframe will be look like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uArW6.png)

My expectation Output is this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFH2G.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please try to format your question in a clearer manner.

Comment: Hi Sam, Alright will do. Thanks for the note.

Answer (score 0):

Look a this snippet, don't forget to handle the first item.
copy paste from ipython.

```
In [10]: id_ =1  
In [11]: for first, second in zip(data, data[1:]): 
    ...:     if first != second: 
    ...:         id_ += 1 
    ...:     print(f'{id_} {second}') 
    ...:      
    ...:
```

see itertools module for more.

Comment: Thanks @cgte but how to add this incremental values in a new column? also your code seems comparing both X and Y column together?.

Comment: Yes because python supports dict comparison.